# Uso de CallBack em Delphi

Tags: delphi-xe3, datasnap

Estou reformulando minha pergunta referente a metodologia CallBack.

Gostaria de algum exemplo ou material especifico de como usar chamadas de CallBacks do servidor para o client.

Exemplo:

**LADO CLIENT**

**No client tenho essa classe TCallBack**

```
TCallback = class(TDBXCallBack)
  Function Execute(const Args: TJSONValue): TJSONValue; override;
  function GetConnectionName(OptionList: OleVariant): String;
  procedure ShowWaitScreen(const Msg: String);
  procedure ReleaseProcessScreen;
  function ShowProcessScreen(const ALinha: String; const ACaption: String;
                          APosition: Integer; ACount2: Integer;):  WordBool;
end;
```

**com o codigo abaixo em algum lugar do client mando o CallBack para o servidor**

```
Var
  FCallBack: TCallBack;
  ClientPx: TSMPrincipalClient;  
begin
  if (FCallBack = nil) then begin
     FCallBack := TCallBack.Create();
  end;
  try
    ClientPx := TSMPrincipalClient.Create(conDataSnap.DBXConnection, False);
    ClientPx.SetCallBack(FCallback);
  except
   on E:Exception do
    ExceptionMessage := e.Message;
  end;
end;
```

**LADO SERVER**

**Apartir de agora que esta a minha duvida,o server recebeu o Callback pelo metodo setCallback**

```
procedure TSMPrincipal.SetCallBack(CallBack: TDBXCallback);
var
  FCallBack: TDBXCallback;
begin
  FCallBack := CallBack;
  FConnection.ConnectionName := GetConnectionName;
  FConnection.Connected := True;
end;
```

Aí em algum ponto do server chamo o método no client, como fazer isso?

```
Result := FCallBack.GetConnectionName(Dataset.Data);
```

Answer (score 3):

Encontrei um [tutorial](http://www.andreanolanusse.com/pt/utilizando-callback-em-datasnap-2010/) bem completo no blog do Andreano Lanusse.

Quando temos uma chamada client-server envolvendo algum tipo de processamento utilizamos o Callback para que o server envie o status do processamento para o cliente. Dito isto, você deve seguir os seguintes passos:

1- Implementar o server Method. Este server method recebe um TDBXCallBack como parâmetro.

No blog o Andreano fez um server method que realiza o backup de um banco de dados, retornando para o cliente a última linha da tabela que foi processada:

```
procedure TDSServerBatch.StartBackup(sMessage: TDBXCallback;
  sBackupFileName: String);
var
  LCallbackValue: TJSONObject;
  db: String;

begin

  db := DMServerContainer.GetEmployeeDBName;

  srvBackup.DatabaseName := Copy(db, Pos(':', db) + 1, Length(db));

  srvBackup.Attach;
  srvBackup.BackupFile.Add(sBackupFileName);

  srvBackup.ServiceStart;
  if srvBackup.Verbose then
    while not srvBackup.Eof do
    begin

      // if srvBackup.IsServiceRunning then
      begin
        LCallbackValue := TJSONObject.Create;
        LCallbackValue.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('Server return',
            srvBackup.GetNextLine));

        sMessage.Execute(LCallbackValue);

      end;

    end;

  if srvBackup.Active then
    srvBackup.Detach();

end;
```

2- Implementar o client-side.

Acho interessante utilizar métodos anônimos para o callback. Por quê? Eu explico: Ao utilizar métodos anônimos a referência do callback a ser executado será passado do server para o cliente, sempre que um de seus server method for executado. Segue o exemplo abaixo:

```
type
  TDSCallbackMethod = reference to function(const Args: TJSONValue): TJSONValue;

  TMessageCallback = class(TDBXCallback)
  private
    FCallBackMethod: TDSCallbackMethod;

  public
    constructor Create(CallBackMethod: TDSCallbackMethod);
    function Execute(const Arg: TJSONValue): TJSONValue; override;
  end;

implementation

constructor TMessageCallback.Create(CallBackMethod: TDSCallbackMethod);
begin
  FCallBackMethod := CallBackMethod;
end;

function TMessageCallback.Execute(const Arg: TJSONValue): TJSONValue;
begin
  Result := FCallbackMethod(Arg);
end;
```

3- Para executar o server method você precisa apenas fazer isso:

```
//Declarar seu callback (Usei Métodos Anônimos)
callback := TMessageCallback.Create( function(const Args: TJSONValue) : TJSONValue;
//No caso, s é do tipo TDSServerBatchClient, que seria seu proxy em questão.
s := TDSServerBatchClient.Create(DMClientContainer.MyDSServer.DBXConnection);
s.StartBackup(callback, 'mybackup.ibk');
```

*P.S.: Apenas para concluir, esta resposta foi baseado no material retirado do blog. A escrevi apenas para termos uma referência aqui no site que não dependa do link. Sugiro que leia o post na integra para melhores conclusões.*

Comment: Obrigado, @EdgarMunizBerlinck !!! Material do Andreano é sempre muito bom. Vou dar uma olhada na integra